# Install Mailchimp without using Composer

Tags: magento-2.1, composer, mailchimp

I have a question about installing *Mailchimp*,

`https://php-download.com/package/mailchimp/mc-magento2`.

Server I'm using doesn't give permission to run *composer*. So I need to manually upload the full package. But I don't know how to do it. I just can't use composer in usual way.
I need to connect `ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib` with *Mailchimp* without using *composer*.

**I'm using magento 2.1.7 Enterprise Cloud.**

Can anyone help me with it please?

Comment: Were you able to download package to the server?

Comment: mailchimp/mc-magento2. It's locally working find. problem is cloud permission they recommendation is set up project locally and push to cloud.

Comment: @Lasantha,looking for the same, any possibilities without composer?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud only allow git add we should install using local git. finally I did it. thanks
1st create a git branch and checkout it.
locally have to install mailchimp using composer then add it to git . git add -A

than commit the change git commit -m " comment"

push the changes. git push origin branch

thats it.

Comment: @jafar pinjar -Answer